# Writing functions in R with loops

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have the following matrix:

```
dists <- structure(c(0, 13.9, 5.2, 42.6, 38.4, 19.7, 7.6, 13.9, 0, 12.3, 
                 33, 19.1, 26.9, 17.8, 5.2, 12.3, 0, 34.7, 30.5, 17.9, 11.7, 42.6, 
                 33, 34.7, 0, 15.7, 21.5, 46.9, 38.4, 19.1, 30.5, 15.7, 0, 17.2, 
                 42.6, 19.7, 26.9, 17.9, 21.5, 17.2, 0, 26.2, 7.6, 17.8, 11.7, 
                 46.9, 42.6, 26.2, 0), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), 
                 .Dimnames = list(c("Berkeley", "SanFrancisco", "Oakland", "PaloAlto", 
                                    "SanMateo", "Hayward", "Richmond"), 
                                  c("Berkeley", "SanFrancisco", "Oakland", "PaloAlto", 
                                    "SanMateo", "Hayward", "Richmond")))
```

The column & row names are city names, and each point of the matrix is the distance (in miles) between the two cities. For example, if my point is [SanFrancisco, Berkeley] the distance is 13.9.

I am trying to figure out a function that given a vector of cities, and the matrix of distances between cities, the function returns the total distance between the provided cities. I know how to make a function where there are only 2 cities involved. How would you make a function where there are mutliple cities involved? (Berkeley -> SanFrancisco->PaloAlto, etc), I figure you have to use some sort of loop. I started off with the function

```
get_distance <- function(cities, dists)
```

where the vector "cities" is defined as

```
cities <- c("Berkeley", "SanFrancisco", "Oakland", 
        "PaloAlto", "SanMateo", "Hayward", "Richmond")
```

I was thinking about how to approach this function. My thought process was to make a function where it will add the sums of pairs of cities such as if you enter in the function `get_distance(c("Berkeley", "Oakland", "SanFrancisco"), dists)`, then it would sum the distance of (Berkeley, Oakland) and (Oakland, SanFrancisco). Then I would have the function use a repeat loop and break until it reaches the number of cities inputted (total number of arguments in the function?). I don't think this is an efficient way to write this function, is there a better way? Here is my attempt at the code but I don't know how to count the variable number of arguments in my function. I tried using narg() and I thought about the dot argument but can't seem to figure it out.

```
 get_distance <- function(cities, dists) {

  i <- 1    #the ith city with i=(1,2,...)       
  number_of_cities = length(cities)
  sum_dist <- 0
  repeat {
    sum_dist <- sum_dist + dist[cities[i-1], cities[i]]
    if (i == number_of_cities) break
    i <- i + 1

    return(dists[cities[i-1], cities[i]]) }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
 get_distance <- function(cities, dists) {
    i <- match(cities, colnames(dists))
    start <- i[-length(i)]
    end <- i[-1]
    sum(dists[cbind(start, end)])
  }

  get_distance(cities, dists)
  #[1] 120
```

But if you really want a loop:

```
 get_distance <- function(cities, dists) {
    d <- 0
    for (i in 2:(length(cities))) {
        d <- d + dists[cities[i-1], cities[i]]
    }
    d
 }
```

Comment: Is using a repeat loop not possible? I would like to see if I can use that approach

Comment: @AndyQuach Is using repeat loop possible? Yes, it. Is it recommended? Probably not. In R, better to avoid loops when it is avoidable.

Comment: It is possible although a for loop would be a more obvious choice here. But this is R; why use loops if there is no need for it? Just to make your code slower and more verbose?

Comment: @RobertH can you explain to me start and end? I don't quite understand it

Comment: `start` is the vector of starting cities for each segment of the journey (all cities visited, except the last one); `end` is the vector of ending cities (all except the first one).